# Maximum likelihood estimation using a step function

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-fitting, log-likelihood

I would like to fit a step function (two parameters) to some data. The code below is not doing the job. I wonder if the `round()` argument is the problem. However, I also tried to divide the parameters to make small (e.g. 0.001) changes in the parameters to cause significant changes. But that did not change the fit. Any idea how to properly fit this function to the data?

```
dat <- c(rbinom(100, 100, 0.95), rbinom(50, 100, 0.01), rbinom(100, 100, 0.95))

plot(dat/100)

stepFnc <- function(parms, t) {
  par <- as.list(parms)
  (c(rep(1-(1e-5), par$t1), rep(1e-5, par$t2), rep(1-(1e-5), t)))[1:t]
}

lines(stepFnc(c(t1 = 50, t2 = 50), length(dat)))

loglik <- function(t1 = 50, t2 = 50) {
    fit <- snowStepCurve(parms = list(t1=round(t1,0), t2=round(t2,0)), t = length(dat))
    lines(fit)
    -sum(dbinom(x = dat, size = 100, prob = fit, log = T), na.rm = T)
}

mle <- bbmle::mle2(loglik)
mle@coef

lines(snowStepCurve(mle@coef, length(dat)), lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = "orange")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With discrete x data I'd do a brute-force approach:

```
x <- seq_along(dat)

foo <- function(x, lwr, upr) {
  y <- x
  y[x <= lwr | x > upr] <- mean(dat[x <= lwr | x > upr])
  y[x > lwr & x <= upr] <- mean(dat[x > lwr & x <= upr])
  y
}

SSE <- function(lwr, upr) {
  sum((dat - foo(x, lwr, upr))^ 2) 
}

limits <- expand.grid(lwr = x, upr = x)
limits <- limits[limits$lwr <= limits$upr,]
nrow(limits)

SSEvals <- mapply(SSE, limits$lwr, limits$upr)

id <- which(SSEvals == min(SSEvals))
optlims <- limits[id,]
meanouter <-  mean(dat[x <= optlims$lwr | x > optlims$upr])
meaninner <- mean(dat[x > optlims$lwr & x <= optlims$upr])

bar <- function(x) {
  y <- x
  y[x <= optlims$lwr | x > optlims$upr] <- meanouter
  y[x > optlims$lwr & x <= optlims$upr] <- meaninner
  y
}

plot(dat/100)
curve(bar(x) / 100, add = TRUE)
```

[image: resulting plot showing the fit]

Comment: Thanks @Roland, that is certainly an option that works. I was hoping to get something that is significantly faster since I need to perform that step (with a slightly more complex dataset) several thousand times.

Comment: Is the signal to noise ratio always as large as in this example? Then you could just search for min and max of `diff(dat)`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not :-) I just wanted to create a simple example

Comment: Implementing this brute force approach in Rcpp should take less than two hours. That might be better than spending more time looking for a more intelligent algorithm.

Comment: I was thinking the same and started doing that! Thanks!!